# How can i get columns added on column?

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

heres my code below...

```
   TableColumn tc = new TableColumn();
    TableColumn[] tc2 = new TableColumn[10];
    for(int i=0; i<5, i++){
      tc.getColumns().add(tc2[i]);
      }
```

and i try to override commit method for editing cells.

```
public void commit(Object val) {

    // Get the table
    TableView<MainTable> t = this.getTableView();

    // Get the selected row/column

    MainTable selectedRow = t.getItems().get(this.getTableRow().getIndex());    
    TableColumn<MainTable, ?> selectedColumn = t.getColumns().get(t.getColumns().indexOf(this.getTableColumn()));

    // Get current property name
    String propertyName = ((PropertyValueFactory) selectedColumn.getCellValueFactory()).getProperty();

    // Create a method name conforming to java standards ( setProperty )
    propertyName = ("" + propertyName.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);

    // Try to run the update
    try {

        // Type specific checks - could be done inside each setProperty() method
        if(val instanceof Double) {
            Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, double.class);
            method.invoke(selectedRow, (double) val);
        }
        if(val instanceof String) {
            Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, String.class);
            method.invoke(selectedRow, (String) val);
        }
        if(val instanceof Integer) {
            Method method = selectedRow.getClass().getMethod("set" + propertyName, int.class);
            method.invoke(selectedRow, (int) val);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // CommitEdit for good luck
    commitEdit((String) val);
}
```

and i got ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException on console view.

so my question is 
how can i select getcolumns added other column???

```
TableColumn<MainTable, ?> selectedColumn = t.getColumns().get(t.getColumns().indexOf(this.getTableColumn()));
```

i think this code has to be changed...
anyone got ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested columns are not part of the `TableView.columns` list.

If you need the corresponding `TableView` column, just go up through the hierarchy until you reach a column without a `parentColumn`:

```
TableColumn<MainTable, ?> selectedColumn = this.getTableColumn();
TableColumn<MainTable, ?> c = selectedColumn;
while ((c = selectedColumn.getParentColumn()) != null) {
    selectedColumn = c;
}
```

If you just need the column itself, simply use `this.getTableColumn()`, instead of finding the index of the column in the `columns` list and then accessing that index in the same list. (I guess the latter is what you need.)

Furthermore, if `PropertyValueFactory` returns properties of the item class, you could use this property to set the value instead of using reflection:

```
ObservableValue obs = selectedColumn.getCellObservableValue(this.getIndex());
if (obs instanceof WritableValue) {
    ((WritableValue) obs).setValue(val);
} else {
    // reflecitive approach
}
```

---

Furthermore you shouldn't add `null` as a nested column, but you're doing it here:

```
TableColumn[] tc2 = new TableColumn[10];
for(int i=0; i<5, i++){
    tc.getColumns().add(tc2[i]);
}
```